# How to output type declarations for custom rollup plugin output

Tags: typescript, rollup

I'm using Rollup for bundling, and I have a custom plugin which transforms some human-readable declarations into JavaScript code.

It works correctly when I import those files with a `// @ts-ignore` before each import:

```
// @ts-ignore
import menu from '../foo/bar/menus/foobar.menu';
```

However, if I remove the ignore declaration, I'm getting:

> (!) Plugin typescript: @rollup/plugin-typescript TS2307: Cannot find module '../foo/bar/menus/foobar.menu' or its corresponding type declarations.

The question is, how I'm expected to output the type declarations from my plugin?

Btw. writing separate declarations by hand, as a *.d.ts* files, is not an option. I need them to be generated.